# AudioKit, exporting AVAudioPCMBuffer array to audio file with fade in/out

Tags: swift, audiokit

I'm capturing audio from AKLazyTap and rendering the accumulated `[AVAudioPCMBuffer]` to an audio file, in the background, while my app's audio is running. This works great, but I want to add fade in/out to clean up the result. I see the convenience extension for adding fades to a single AVAudioPCMBuffer, but I'm not sure how I'd do it on an array. I'd thought to concatenate the buffers, but there doesn't appear to be support for that. Does anyone know if that's currently possible? Basically it would require something similar to `copy(from:readOffset:frames)`, but would need to have a write offset as well...

Or maybe there's an easier way?

- UPDATE

Okay, after studying some related AK code, I tried directly copying buffer data over to a single, long buffer, then applying the fade convenience function. But this gives me an empty (well, 4k) file. Is there some obvious error here that I'm just not seeing?

```
func renderBufferedAudioToFile(_ audioBuffers: [AVAudioPCMBuffer], withStartOffset startOffset: Int, endOffset: Int, fadeIn: Float64, fadeOut: Float64, atURL url: URL) {
    // strip off the file name
    let name = String(url.lastPathComponent.split(separator: ".")[0])

    var url = self.module.stateManager.audioCacheDirectory

    // UNCOMPRESSED
    url = url.appendingPathComponent("\(name).caf")
    let format = Conductor.sharedInstance.sourceMixer.avAudioNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    var settings = format.settings
    settings["AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved"] = false

    // temp buffer for fades
    let totalFrameCapacity = audioBuffers.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.frameLength }
    guard let tempAudioBufferForFades = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: totalFrameCapacity) else {
        print("Failed to create fade buffer!")
        return
    }

    // write ring buffer to file.
    let file = try! AVAudioFile(forWriting: url, settings: settings)

    var writeOffset: AVAudioFrameCount = 0
    for i in 0 ..< audioBuffers.count {
        var buffer = audioBuffers[i]
        let channelCount = Int(buffer.format.channelCount)
        if i == 0 && startOffset != 0 {
            // copy a subset of samples in the buffer
            if let subset = buffer.copyFrom(startSample: AVAudioFrameCount(startOffset)) {
                buffer = subset
            }
        } else if i == audioBuffers.count - 1 && endOffset != 0 {
            if let subset = buffer.copyTo(count: AVAudioFrameCount(endOffset)) {
                buffer = subset
            }
        }
        // write samples into single, long buffer
        for i in 0 ..< buffer.frameLength {
            for n in 0 ..< channelCount {
                tempAudioBufferForFades.floatChannelData?[n][Int(i + writeOffset)] = (buffer.floatChannelData?[n][Int(i)])!
            }
        }
        print("buffer \(i), writeOffset = \(writeOffset)")
        writeOffset = writeOffset + buffer.frameLength
    }
    // update!
    tempAudioBufferForFades.frameLength = totalFrameCapacity 

    if let bufferWithFades = tempAudioBufferForFades.fade(inTime: fadeIn, outTime: fadeOut) {
        try! file.write(from: bufferWithFades)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, got it! Needed to update the concatenated buffer's frameLength: `tempAudioBufferForFades.frameLength = totalFrameCapacity`. I guess I just assumed the initializer would provide this, but I guess it only sets the (potential) capacity, rather than actually determining the length. Will update the code for anybody in need of a similar solution.